# How can I access "information_schema" with typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

Trying to query `information_schema` with typeorm and it's failing, how can I access this data with typeorm?

> QueryFailedError: relation "   information_schema.columns" does not exist

```js
const rawData = await connection.query(`
SELECT
   COLUMN_NAME
FROM
   information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
   TABLE_NAME = 'members';
`);
```

Comment: I created library for this purpose - https://github.com/Ginden/typeorm-information-schema

Answer (score 1):

Had to modify the query:

```js
const rawData = await connection.query(`
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM "information_schema"."columns" 
WHERE ("table_schema" = 'public' AND "table_name" = 'members')
`);
```

Found here https://wanago.io/2019/01/28/typeorm-migrations-postgres/